# Has_many through and path helper - accessing resources through the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have an app in which users can follow law firms

I have 3 models 
- User
- Firm
- Follow

```
class Firm < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :follows, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :follows

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :follows, :dependent => :destroy 
has_many :firms, :through => :follows

class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :firm
belongs_to :user
```

In a table in my firms index view, I would like to take the current signed and create an association between that user and the law firm - through the follow table.

In effect doing this -
            firm.users << User(current)

This is the code that I have at present, how would you suggest that I structure the path, and the corresponding controller?

```
<% @firms.each do |firm| %>
  <tr id = "firm_<%= firm.id %>">
    <td><%= link_to image_tag(firm.logo_url, :size => "80x120"), firm.url %></td>
    <td><%= link_to firm.name, firm_path(firm) %></td>  
    <% if user_signed_in? %><td>
    <%= button_to 'Follow',  ? , method: :post %>
    </td>
    <% end %>
```

I am using devise for the User authentication and have put the following helpers into application helper to allow my login partial to function in a different models view.

```
  def resource_name
:user
end

def resource_id
 :user_id
end

def resource
@resource ||= User.new
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to have a `follow` action on a `FirmsController`.

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :firms do
  post :follow, on: :member
end
```

In your `FirmsController`:

```
def follow
  @firm.users << current_user
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_firm_path(@firm), method: :post %>
```

Another way would be to represent a follow relationship as a singular resource. You'd follow a firm by `POST`ing to `/firms/1234/follow` and you'd unfollow a firm by sending a `DELETE` request to `/firms/1234/follow`.

If you wanted to take that approach, you'd stick this in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :firms do
  resource :follow, on: :member
end
```

And you'd create a `FollowsController` like this:

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @firm = Firm.find params[:firm_id]
    @firm.users << current_user
    # respond with success
  end

  def destroy
    @firm = Firm.find params[:firm_id]
    @firm.users.delete current_user
    # respond with success
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for lending me a hand! I have tried both of these, and in both cases rails seems to be throwing its toys out of the pram over the the follow method.  

    No route matches {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"firms"}

I shall let you know if i solve it!

Comment: This does appear when i type in rake routes

follow_firm POST   /firms/:id/follow(.:format)   firms#follow

how should i be defining the follow method in the firms controller?
perhaps that is my problem?